# Getting size of Kinetic.Path

Tags: kineticjs

Is there a way to get width and height of a Kinetic.Path object? It always returns zero.

```
var path = new Kinetic.Path({
    x: 40,
    y: 40,
    data: "m 148.57143,-1.9235271 200,82.8571401 L 257.14286,300.93361 2.8571414,263.79075 z",
    stroke: "green",
    draggable: true
});

layer.add(path);

stage.draw();

console.log(path.getWidth()); // returns zero
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KineticJS doesn't calculate a path's bounding box. You'll have to calculate them yourself using the path's data. For that, I've written code to handle those paths.

https://gist.github.com/4075955

However, the code currently only supports lines, not curves or arcs. The code is released to the public domain, so I encourage anyone to modify it.

Example:

```
var dimensions=getPathDimensions(path);
var width=dimensions.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no sort of metrics functionality was not built into the Path shape (i.e., to get height, width, etc).

Well, aside from length:

Kinetic.Path.calcLength = function(x, y, cmd, points)

(intended to be used only for individual elements in the path, i.e., elements of the parsed Path.dataarray)